# Calling multiple, independent shells in Heroku

Tags: shell, heroku, command

I am looking for this kind of shell scripting equivalent in Heroku dynos.

```
start cmd /k call "batch1.bat" 
start cmd /k call "batch2.bat"
```

I tried

```
. batch1.sh &
. batch2.sh &
```

Even this one crashed.

```
./batch1.sh &
```

Would like to know if Heroku supports this activity. If yes, kindly help me with the correct set of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spin up a heroku [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dynos), as follows:

```
heroku run bash
```

This gives you an interactive bash shell, from which you can invoke any script in your git repo.

You can also, of course, run "batch" scripts directly, e.g:

```
heroku run bash -c "ls -lt"
```

That will spin up a one-off dyno instance, whose bash shell will run whatever command was passed to it, in this case, "ls -lt". After completing the command, the one-off dyno shuts down.

Note that as with all Heroku dynos, the filesystem is ephemeral, so any files created by your script will be gone after your one-off dyno exits.